# How to insert a Part into another plug-in's PartStack in Eclipse 4 RCP?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I'd like to practice Eclipse 4 RCP application development, and my current goal is a graph modeling application. As far as I know GEF (Graphical Editing Framework) is the most reliable graphical framework, but it is Eclipse 3.x only. So I decided to create a plug-in only for the editor but I don't know how to insert the graphical editor's Part into the main plug-in's Application Model. What's more, how two plug-ins can communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins communicate through extension points, there are certain extension points defined by plugins to allow extending existing functionality. So I would suggest you reading about those things. Then find out if which extension points does plugin you are interested in offers and extend it. You may find extension points definitions in plugin.xml or in the documentation.